# Setting up MAMP - changing password

Tags: mysql, mamp

New to php, mysql and apache, but not to html/css and web design. Have downloaded MAMP to create new joomla website offline (also fairly new to joomla).

Following instructions in MAMP documentation and dwuser.com/education/content/why-you-need-a-testing-server-and-how-to-do-it/ and other sources (though am wary of non-official sites and years old info). It seems all is installed correctly (the message says so).

Trying to change the password of the mysql root user via Terminal app (inexperienced in console work too, sorry). After entering the correct text and substituting new password I am prompted for a password. There's a grey upright box with a white circle at the spot where I'd enter this old password ('root'). If I switch away from the terminal window the box becomes an outlined version.

Have tried limiting the new pw to all lowercase (12 characters), putting in computer admin password, and also searching to find out what the box means (unsuccessfully).

Also tried continuing setup by changing the password in the config.inc.php file (just in case) but afterwards password error messages came up.

Searching on the password error part has shown others have had problems but the replies have been beyond me, hopefully my knowledge will advance in time.

I hope some kind person will point me in the right direction... please? (In fairly simple terms too please).

Many thanks in advance.

.....
more info via edit

In the console I am keying

/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p password [NewPassword]

and substituting a new password (random 12 character) for [NewPassword]. After 'enter', the following line shows

Enter password: "grey sq box here"

and at this point nothing can be entered in the console.

So I know something's already amiss.

Thanks for your help...

Comment: can you describe your situation more detail? As far as I understand, you know the password of 'root' user of mysql right?

Comment: Thanks for your fast response Dev. The default password for 'root' user is 'root'. I changed this to a random new password, perhaps I am meant to use a password already in use somewhere else?

Comment: a ha, then tell me your operation system type. (Linux, Windows, Mac...)

Comment: it's Mac, thanks. Also have given some more info via an edit.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain as detail as possible.
I believe you can execute the terminal.

0.Move to mampstack folder

`$cd /Applications/MAMP/`

1. stop mysql service

`$sudo ./ctlscript.sh stop mysql`

`Password:"your_macbook_user_password"`

2.Command not to look at grant table(which requires password input)

`$/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`

3.You can enter mysql root directly due to 2nd process

`mysql -u root mysql`

4. change the password with the update query

`mysql>update user set password=password('new-passwd') where user = 'root';`

5. quit the mysql

`mysql>flush privileges;`

`mysql>quit`

6. restart the mysql

`service mysqld restart` `service mysql restart` Try both

Comment: Thanks Dev, that is really helpful, not that I understand some of it. I will have a stab now.

Comment: Tried both in step 1, but I get the message:  -bash: service: command not found    Should I be doing this in the computer's Administrator account?

Comment: @wateringcan added some contents. If you can, add comment with result of `$cd /Applications/MAMP/` `$ls`

Comment: Got Step 0 done. Now Step 1 results in ./ctlscript.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: at the step 0, do `$ls` and give the result to me. Don't hurry.

Comment: /Applications/MAMP/: is a directory    But not sure this is what you were expecting? Sorry if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I knew more when using Windows but new to Mac. But still not much. I am typing in exactly as given and hitting enter.

Comment: not $ls ? Entering 'ls' as is lists various locations on the computer 'Desktop' etc.

Comment: I think this may be getting too complicated for me, I'm not comfortable working in the console. I will ask someone to come in and set up MAMP for me. Thanks all the same for your kind help Dev.